# The condition is necessary for the existence of a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We have the following problem $$v_{tt}=c^2v_{xx}, \ x>0, t>0 \\ v(x,0)=\phi (x) , \ x\geq 0 \\ v_t(x,0)=\psi (x), \ x\geq 0\\ v_x(0,t)=0 , \ t\geq 0$$ I want to find a function $v$ that satifies the above problem. Then I want to show that the conditions $\phi '(0)=\psi '(0)=0$ are necessary for the existence of a smooth solution of the problem.

$$$$

The function that saatisfies the conditions (except the last one) is given by d'Alembert's formula, right?

So we have $$v(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[\phi (x-ct]+\phi (x+ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\psi (\xi)d\xi$$ Then we have to take the partial derivative as for $x$ to use the last condition, right?

Then we have $$ v_x(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[\phi' (x-ct)+\phi' (x+ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}[-\psi (x-ct)+\psi (x+ct)]$$ Is this correct?

Then we get $$v_x(0,t)=0\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}[\phi' (-ct)+\phi' (ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}[-\psi (-ct)+\psi (ct)]=0$$ What do we get from here? Do we calculate that at $t=0$ ?

Comment: If you take $t\to 0$ then you get $\phi'(0) = 0$. Take the derivative and put $t\to 0$ to get $\psi'(0) = 0$. Note that these are necessary, but not sufficient, conditions for the solution to exist.

Comment: When we take the derivative we have the second derivative of $\phi$ at $0$. Is this thenequal to $0$ ? @Winther

Comment: The two terms cancel: $-\phi''(0) + \phi''(0) = 0$ just as $-\psi(0) + \psi(0) = 0$ cancel when you take $t=0$ in the equation for $v_x(0,t)$

Comment: Oh yes, right! Thank you very much!! :-) @Winther

Comment: And why are these necessary, but not sufficient, conditions for the solution to exist? @Winther

Comment: Because they are not enough. The most general condition is $\frac{1}{2}[\phi'(-x) + \phi(x)] + \frac{1}{2c}[-\psi(-x) + \psi(x)] = 0$ for all $x \geq 0$. But for example $\phi(x) = x^3$ and $\psi(x) = x^2$ has $\phi'(0) = \psi'(0) = 0$, but $\frac{1}{2}[3(-ct)^2 + 3(cy)^2] + \frac{1}{2c}[-(ct)^2 + (ct)^2] = 3(ct)^2 \not = 0$ so even if the condition is satisfied we don't have $v_x(0,t) = 0$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Comment: Ah ok! And this condition is necessary because of $v_x(0,t)=0$ or why? @Winther